# How to convert a returned WndProc/DlgProc handle into a function address?

Tags: c, winapi

In the following call, the `WndProc` can be [returned as a handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
FARPROC pfn = (FARPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 
    DWLP_DLGPROC);  //same with GWLP_WNDPROC
```

Is there a way to convert it to address from a user-mode code?

Comment: I don't think that description is meant to be read as: "... and so you can treat it as such". It's just a value of *some* type, only meant to be passed on to [`CallWindowProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571(v=vs.85).aspx) (which also does not care what type it is).

Comment: Why do you need to know? I'm smelling an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: exist `GetWindowLongPtrW` and `GetWindowLongPtrA` - based as window procedure Unicode or ansi - one version returned handle, another procedure address

Comment: @zett42 - I don't know for what this is need for OP, but this is need if we write tool like Spy++ - by given windows handle - display for user information about window, window procedure address as well. for debugging and research this info is very useful

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, correct. I'm writing a debugging, RE, malware analysis tool. The goal here is to know the exact `WndProc` address in the target process, (as well as `DlgProc` for dialog windows.)

Comment: so `(IsWindowUnicode(hwnd) ? 
    GetWindowLongPtrW : GetWindowLongPtrA)(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);` give to you exactly function address.

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, thanks. I just read your full explanation below. Totally makes sense. I hate that I didn't see it myself :) So in other words, if I call `GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, DWLP_DLGPROC);` on a Unicode window it will **always** return a pointer and **not** a handle, correct?

Comment: yes. the same - `IsWindowUnicode(hwnd) ? GetWindowLongPtrW : GetWindowLongPtrA` - `GWLP_WNDPROC` or `DWLP_DLGPROC` - no different

Comment: yes, this is right. however need check, what be in this case. need create poc

Comment: @RbMm: I'll remove my bug comment. Need to look into it first... thanks.

Comment: i check - really if window proc in `0xffff0000` mask (this is can be legal address for x64 - simply set `/BASE:0xffff0000` and `/FIXED` linker option) - the `HMValidateHandleNoRip` called. but it return false and after this direct call by this address. so this is only **first fast check**

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, you're right. It can recover from it. So I don't think they'll be fixing it any time soon. At the worst it wastes CPU cycles for looking up a nonexistent handle. I'll try to report it just for completeness. We'll see if they care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need next code:

```
PVOID pfn = (IsWindowUnicode(hwnd) ? 
    GetWindowLongPtrW : GetWindowLongPtrA)(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
```

so you need call `GetWindowLongPtrW` or `GetWindowLongPtrA` based on result of `IsWindowUnicode`

---

note: `GetWindowLongPtrA(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` and `GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` - always return different result - one address of the window procedure and another - handle representing the address of the window procedure : special internal value meaningful only to `CallWindowProc` - for determine which version **A** or **W** retrieves the address of the window procedure - need call `IsWindowUnicode`. this is undocumented, but reasonable. if subclassed procedure have the same ANSI or UNICODE native that original procedure it can direct call original. if native is different - need translation (Unicode <-> ANSI) for window messages (as example `WM_GETTEXT`, `WM_SETTEXT`..).

fact that `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)` must return the same value as `SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWindowProc)`

but `SetWindowLongPtrA` set the ansi window procedure (which say got pointer to `CHAR` string in `WM_SETTEXT`) and `SetWindowLongPtrW` set the unicode window procedure (which say got pointer to `WCHAR` string in `WM_SETTEXT`). so if current window procedure and new set by `SetWindowLongPtr` have the same **A** or **W** - new procedure can direct call old, without translation, and absolute reasonable that `SetWindowLongPtr` return direct address of old windows procedure. if native is different - (we set A for W or W for A) - new window procedure can not direct call old. before this some windows messages need to be translated (`WM_GETTEXT`, `WM_SETTEXT`, etc). because this and handle returned and `CallWindowProc` translate message before call original procedure.

---

example which show that `IsWindowUnicode` can return different values for the same window - based on current window procedure - are it ansi or Unicode:

```
if (HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExA(0, WC_STATICA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) {

    DbgPrint("IsWindowUnicode=%x\n", IsWindowUnicode(hwnd));

    LONG_PTR l = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);

    SetWindowLongPtrA(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, l);

    DbgPrint("IsWindowUnicode=%x\n", IsWindowUnicode(hwnd));

    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, l);

    DbgPrint("IsWindowUnicode=%x\n", IsWindowUnicode(hwnd));

    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
}
```

and output:

```
IsWindowUnicode=1
IsWindowUnicode=0
IsWindowUnicode=1
```

so what say documentation:

> The character set of a window is determined by the use of the
>   **RegisterClass** function. If the window class was registered with the
>   ANSI version of **RegisterClass** (**RegisterClassA**), the character set of
>   the window is ANSI. If the window class was registered with the
>   Unicode version of **RegisterClass** (**RegisterClassW**), the character set
>   of the window is Unicode.

not exactly correct. it based on current window procedure Ansi or Unicode. initially this is based on `RegisterClass` but can be changed by `SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWindowProc)`

Comment: Anyway, I just learned something today. This is crazy. I had no idea that someone can change ANSI to Unicode window class type after its creation (and vice versa) by calling `SetWindowLongPtr`

Comment: @c00000fd - yes. can. documentation is incomplete at this point. however you can simply run and test my code snippet

Comment: @c00000fd - somebody send `WM_SETTEXT` to window. window proc must got pointer to `WCHAR` or `CHAR` text string ? this is depend form are windows ansi or unicode. but if we subclass window with `SetWindowLongPtrX(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWindowProc)` - new procedure must got ansi or unicode string ? this must based on initial window creation or on `SetWindowLongPtrA` vs `SetWindowLongPtrW` ? documentation nothing say about this. always need think yourself

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not really make sense. If you have the window procedure in your own code - more exactly in one of the application modules - `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_DLGPROC);` will return that address. It only returns a handle when no explicit window procedure exists and it is then

> ... a special internal value meaningful only to CallWindowProc.

That means that the messages are directly processed by Windows internal code, and you should not even try to guess how(*): it is private to Windows system.

---

(*) The only exception is if you are building a low level library like those from sysinternals that do use undocumented functions and structures.

Comment: question have sense if we write some tool like Spy++ and want show window procedure address for concrete window - we not need call window proc, but show it address

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks for your understanding. This site is full of hot shots that are eager to issue their pointless & pithy comments without understanding the question. You answer below is spot on. Plus I just learned something today. Very cool stuff!